# How to programmatically get the NID of the current node

Tags: nodes

I've pored over [this old thread on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/160921#comment-5138810) and it just kind of makes my head spin around. Pulling down the path and trying to parse out the NID from within it? There has to be a better way.

And solutions like

```
global $node;
$nid = $node->nid;
```

don't work in my custom module (though I'm told they work in templates?). No error or anything, it just instantiates `$node` with a `NULL` value.

It feels like there must be something really obvious that I'm missing.

So, how do you get the NID of the current node without a template, while following best practices and building a reasonably robust module?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Assuming your code is running for a node page, the methods I see used most often in core/contrib modules are either using [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) or [`arg()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7):

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = $node->nid;
}
```

or

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = arg(1);

  // Load the node if you need to
  $node = node_load($nid);
}
```

I personally prefer the first method (even though assignment in condition isn't considered a good idea by some people), but both are perfectly valid.

Comment: You don't _need_ to combine assignment with a condition to use menu_get_object though. :) Otherwise I agree, unless you're using [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools), menu_get_object() is the way to go.

Comment: @Letharion Yeah I feel just a little bit guilty every time I do it ;)

Comment: Neither of those appears to work. When I do `dsm(menu_get_object());` (with `dsm()` being [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)'s way of displaying the contents of objects and arrays), I just get an empty line.

Comment: @beth What function are you calling it from? And is it definitely a node page you're calling it on?

Comment: @Clive Ah, I was calling it on a Webform page. Though I thought Webforms get NIDs as well?

Comment: Yeah they should be nodes as well...is it possible you're on a webform results page/sub page of some sort? Then it wouldn't be a node page as such

Comment: @Letharion I'm using ctools... will it interfere with something?

Comment: No, it definitely won't interfere, but Page manager is how I always solve this problem. That's a whole different way of thinking though, and not suitable for these comments.

Comment: Neither of these methods work with path aliasing enabled.

Comment: @beth They 100% will work with path aliasing enabled. Path aliasing has nothing to do with the _router path_ of the menu item, which is `node/1`, `node/2` etc. If you're still having trouble it might be worth posting another question with the exact code you're using, and provide a bit of context. Then we might be able to pinpoint where the problem's happening

Comment: A single line solution `$nid = ($node = menu_get_object()) ? $node->nid : NULL;`

Comment: Loading the node is rather heavy, I prefer to use the method I outline below, working with the path.

Comment: @sheldonkreger The node's already loaded by that point, `menu_get_object()` (or even `node_load()`) is just getting it from static cache. Even if you call it early on, it's still going to be loaded by a core module later on in the page build (as this is a node page), in that case you'd just be warming the static cache for the next process

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to do this in Drupal 8 since arg() no longer works:

```
$path_args = explode('/', current_path());
print $path_args[1];
```

[Change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274705)

Comment: This also works in Drupal 7. However, if you are on a page which isn't a node, such as admin/structure/blocks , then you will receive an invalid value (in this case, 'structure'). Simply check to see if path_args[1] is an integer and you're probably fine.

Comment: You will likely want to use arg(1) instead of explode, since it has already done that for you:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7

Comment: @RobLoach but arg() doesn't exist in D8

Answer (score 4):

`arg(0)` returns 'node' and `arg(1)` returns node nid.

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In D8:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

Comment: Better wrap the output like shown in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/145826/15055. And also worth to note that this won't work on node preview pages and node revision pages.

Comment: This is the cleanest answer for d8 if looking for a node.

Answer (score 1):

The second method in the currently [accepted answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/32310/9158) is the cleanest in D7. The first answer:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = $node->nid;
}
```

is only visually cleaner. In fact, `menu_get_object()` is calling quite a lot of code and may lead to unforeseen errors. I was using it inside a `hook_node_grants()` function and ran into a PHP Fatal error:

> Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

The explanation, found at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/69232/9158

> The infinite loop you are noticing is caused from the fact that
>   `menu_get_object()` causes Drupal to verify the currently logged-in user
>   has access to the node, which causes your implementation of
>   `hook_node_grants()` to be invoked again, which calls `menu_get_object()`,
>   which causes your implementation of `hook_node_grants()` to be invoked
>   again, which...

This was solved by using the second method:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = arg(1);

  // Load the node if you need to
  $node = node_load($nid);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option, in D7:

```
function _my_module_get_nid() {
  $path_args = explode('/', current_path());
  //$nid = $path_args[1];
  if(is_int($path_args)) {
    return($path_args[1]);
  }
  // Log that we failed to load a NID.
  else {
    watchdog('my_module', 'Unable to gather NID at: ' . current_path(),  WATCHDOG_WARNING, NULL);
  return FALSE;
  }
}
```

If you plan to use the function outside your module, do not use the leading _ at the begining of the name of the function.

Comment: This is the same thing but with an expensive watchdog call on all paths that aren't nodes.

Comment: I like to know if my code is failing unexpectedly. I wouldn't want this code being executed on non-nodes, watchdog will show me where that is happening so I can fix it. Otherwise I'll have no trace that this code is running for no reason (on non-nodes). Otherwise it's the same as the D8 method mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if (isset($node->nid) && count($node->nid) > 0){
  $mynodeid = $node->nid;
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please add some "whys" and "hows" to your answer?Code-only answer might work, but it hardly helps to understand one's mistakes.

Comment: It first checks if the node is defined before executing.

Comment: `count($node->nid) > 0` where `$node->nid` is an integer doesn't make any sense, since `count()` counts the number of items in an array. It's would causes a _PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable_.