# Why is arg() failing to get the router object on pages with aliased URLs?

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

So I posted [this question about how to get NID of current node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-nid-of-the-current-node-from-a-module-not-a/32310#comment32370_32310) and I'm assured that arg() should work to return the router item for the current page, regardless of aliasing. However, it doesn't work.

The relevant snippet is

```
if(arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1))){ 
   $nid = arg(1); 
   dsm($nid);
}
```

I've also tried

```
$load = node_load();
$dsm($load);
```

and

```
$item = menu_get_item();
dsm ($item);
```

and

```
$node = menu_get_object();
dsm($node);
```

For all of these methods, they work when I edit the page (and thus make the URL displayed become `/node/%/edit`) and when I just navigate to `/node/%` (where `%` is the NID) but they display either nothing or (in the case of `arg()`) only the alias (e.g. "about-our-company for the path alias `/about-our-company`).

How can I reliably get the NID of the current node?

Comment: Where did you place your php code?  In a module (which hook?), in a node, in a block, somewhere else?

Comment: Where are you calling your code from? If it's in a template file then the results of the  `dsm()` call will likely be delayed by one page, which might give the impression it's not working.

Comment: It's in a module.

Comment: @beth Help us help you :) *where* in your module file? What hook is it in? And what are you actually trying to accomplish here? There might be an easier way

Comment: It's not in anything. I haven't written anything else in the module yet. Is it really so complicated to find out the NID of the current node?

Comment: @beth No, it's extremely easy (as evidenced by the answer to this and your previous questions, and the subsequent upvotes on those answers). But you can't bake bread without knowing how to use the oven; if you have little to no concept of how Drupal modules work (which is likely since your code is not inside a hook) then you're always going to struggle trying to write one. If you can be more verbose about what it is you're trying to accomplish, what exactly you want to do with the `nid` once you've got it, etc, then we'll be able to give you the advice you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is failing because you're putting it directly in the module file, and not using the hook system. I won't go into exactly why this won't work, if you read the [Module Developer's Guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) it'll make sense.

It's a bit tricky to advise what hook your code should be going in as you don't mention what you want to do with it. As an example, though, lets say you want to extract the `nid` from the current page and pass it to an external service somewhere outside of Drupal.

There are several different ways to do it; at the most basic level, you could use [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7), which is called on every page load. Using this method your calls to `menu_get_object()` and `arg()` will yield the result you're expecting:

```
function MODULENAME_init() {
  $node = menu_get_object();

  if (isset($node->nid)) {
    send_data_to_external_service($node->nid);
  }
}
```

That's all fine, but let's say you want to change the content of a node based on it's `nid`. `hook_init()` will be no good for this, as it has no node available to manipulate in the current context.

Instead, Drupal actually provides a hook that is called when any node in the system is prepared for view, allowing you to manipulate the content. This hook is called [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), and can be used like this:

```
function MODULENAME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full') { // Node is being viewed on it's full node page
    $node->content['my_additional_field'] = array(
      '#markup' => $additional_field, 
      '#weight' => 10, 
      '#theme' => 'mymodule_my_additional_field',
    );
  }
}
```

Notice that one of the arguments that's passed to the function is the `$node` object, which contains the `nid` as a property. As you have this object in the current context, there's no need to query `menu_get_object()` or `arg()` to get the `nid`.

There are [dozens of different hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7) in Drupal that respond to different system events, and allow your custom modules to have a say in how a page is displayed/how data is saved/etc. It might be a good exercise to read through that list and see which hooks would help with the development of your own module.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for pointing out my mistake. This actually clarified my understanding of Drupal rather than just providing a workaround.

Comment: No worries, have a look at [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26290/what-is-basic-concept-behind-hooks) too, the answers do a great job of explaining what the hook system is and how it's used

Answer (score 3):

arg() is intended to work with system paths. if you are viewing you node page with system path (node/#) or by alias then arg(1) must return nid of the node.

How are you defining your alias? Are you using path module interface?
Perhaps the alias is a result of a custom menu hook by some module, rendering a node by some arbitrary logic.

I would also like to share a hack to overcome this issue if you get alias in arg() and this alias is truly defined by path module directly on node then [drupal_lookup_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/7)('source', 'your/node/alias') will return the system path of your node e.g. `node/#`

Comment: I agree with the first two paragraphs, but `drupal_lookup_path()` will only return `node/%` if the provided alias is actually an alias of the node. If that were true, `arg()` and `menu_get_object()` would already work

Comment: Aliases are being generated by Pathauto.

Comment: @Clive, Yes I intended as you said. I have updated the statement.