# How can I check if the author of the current node is the current logged in user?

Tags: nodes, users, rules

I am trying to execute a Rule based on the condition of whether the currently logged in user, is currently viewing their node (a node they are the author of), or viewing someone else's node. The Rule event/trigger I am using is "User saves a Status" from [Statuses](https://drupal.org/project/statuses) module. Next I have used the Rules condition "Execute Custom PHP code", and set an if statement that checks whether the current node uid (the uid of the node's author) equals the current user uid:

```
if ($node->uid == $user->uid) {
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

This is causing a bunch of "Trying to get property of non-object" errors, as both the `$node` and `$user` variables are not being recognised. I'm not sure why this is the case, do I need to use the `node_load()` and `user_load()` functions before using these variables? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to work it out! Below is the code for checking whether the current user is viewing content they are an author of:

```
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = arg(1);

  // Load the node if you need to
  $node = node_load($nid);
}

if($node->uid == $user->uid){
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: This was indeed useful to me

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write any PHP code to achive that.

1. Create a new rule
2. React on event: **Content is viewed** (under **Node** section)
3. Add condition: **Data comparison** (under **Data** section). Continue.
4. Data to compare, data selector: **node:author**. Continue.
5. Data value, data selector: **site:current-user**. Save.

#### UPDATE:

According to you latest edit, my above answer becomes invalid. As I already written in comments, I am not sure if `$node` object is loaded in your script, however I am almost sure that the `$user` object is not. You can load the currently logged in user adding:

```
global $user;
```

at the beginning of you code block. Since I never used PHP in UI, I am not sure if there are tokens available to use. Look around the UI to find out this information, and if they are available, try to make use of them in your code.

Comment: Yes I do know about the data comparison condition but my Rule event/trigger is actually "User saves a Status" from the Statuses module (https://drupal.org/project/statuses), not "Content is viewed". This is why I tried using PHP since the node:author token isn't available when using the above Rule event/trigger. Any advice how I could do this?

Comment: Please add this info to your question.

Comment: Did you enabled 'Statues Rules' module?

Comment: I have updated my question, and yes Statuses Rules is enabled. If there is a way to do this without the custom PHP I would prefer it, but I haven't been able to find one yet which is why I'm trying to do things this way.

Comment: I didn't use PHP code execution in Rules before, since I am not a friend of using PHP code in UI (which has security implications). I cannot help you much about that, since I am not sure if the `$node` object is already loaded. However I am almost sure that the `$user` object is not. Please add `global $user;` just before your code and try again.

Comment: Ok I tried that and it did lower the number of errors but it didn't perform the Rule action. Thank you for that. Now assuming the $node has not been already loaded as you had suggested, how would I load it in the PHP code so I can test whether that is in fact the issue?

Comment: You can use `$node = node_load($nid);` to load the node object but you need to get the node id. That's why I was asking if there are tokens available.

Comment: Yes there are tokens available, I have updated my code in the question above. I have been trying all sorts of token combinations to get this working. There are no errors now but the Rule never actually gets passed as true now, or at least its "Action" is never triggered. Is there something wrong with my code above?

Comment: Ok I worked it out! But apparently I can't answer my question until 8 hours have passed. I'll have to wait to post my answer then. This website was a big help though: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-nid-of-the-current-node-from-a-module-not-a

Answer (score 0):

I have a little bit of a different method. It's very similar to FrontEnd's method, but I try to stay away from arg() as much as possible (for better or worse). It uses menu_get_object() so this won't work in D8, but I've not moved into D8 yet for anything I'm doing.

Here she is:

```
global $user;
// Logged in user
$uid = $user->uid;

$node = menu_get_object();
if (!empty($node)) {
  // Node creator ID
  $nuid = $node->uid;
}

if ($uid==$nuid) {
  $creator = TRUE;
} else {
  $creator = FALSE;
}
```

Then, if I need to display specific information to the content creator I just use:

```
if ($creator) {
  // Hello Creator
}
```

Now I've got uid of the logged in user and the content creator to use further down the function as well.