# How do I get the current node ID?

Tags: nodes, 8

In Drupal 7, if I wanted to get the node id of the currently displayed node (e.g. `node/145`) I could get it with the `arg()` function. In this case, `arg(1)` would return 145.

How can I achieve the same in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The parameter will have been upcasted from nid to full node object by the time you get access to it, so:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
  // You can get nid and anything else you need from the node object.
  $nid = $node->id();
}
```

See the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274705) for more information.

Comment: I just want to add you have to careful with this - I just got stung where \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node'); will return an array of 1 item (the node id) on node revision delete pages, so if you calling a method on what you assume to be an object you will get a fatal error like "Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on string".

Comment: How can I get parameter, if I visited `/taxonomy/term/{tid}`?

Comment: Is this a functional replacement for ```menu_get_object```?

Comment: Pretty much yes @Frank. It’s a bit different of course, but if you’re dropped in a context that doesn’t know what entity page (if any) it’s on, this is the recommended way to find out

Comment: @AshwinP The parameter is whatever you write inside `{}` in your route. For taxonomy terms the route paramater is called `taxonomy_term`, route definition `/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}`. Here you can get it like this, `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term')`.

Comment: BTW, there's a d.o issue to resolve the revision inconsistency: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2730631

Comment: This code isn't working for *unpublished* node when the user doesn't have the permission to see it.
This code `$node = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->get('node');` will correctly load the node.

Comment: As Jeff said, on the revisions urls, $node won't be a loaded instance of Node but a string. the node string, not the revision node id. 
/node/1653/revisions/2188/view 
Be carefull

Comment: The check against NodeInterface should no longer be needed as Drupal now consistently upcasts on node revision routes, see this change record from May 2021: https://www.drupal.org/node/2942013

Answer (score 24):

It is correct to use `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')`. If you just need the node ID, you can use `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node')`.

Answer (score 8):

Note on the node preview page, the following doesn't work:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$nid = $node->id();
```

For the node preview page, you have to load the node this way:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview');
$nid = $node->id();
```

[How to load node object in node preview page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246596/how-to-load-node-object-in-node-preview-page)

Answer (score 6):

if you are using or creating custom block then you have to follow this code to get current url node id.

```
// add libraries
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;  

// code to get nid

$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $node->id()  // get current node id (current url node id)


// for cache

public function getCacheTags() {
  //With this when your node change your block will rebuild
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
  //if there is node add its cachetag
    return Cache::mergeTags(parent::getCacheTags(), array('node:' . $node->id()));
  } else {
    //Return default tags instead.
    return parent::getCacheTags();
  }
}

public function getCacheContexts() {
  //if you depends on \Drupal::routeMatch()
  //you must set context of this block with 'route' context tag.
  //Every new route this block will rebuild
  return Cache::mergeContexts(parent::getCacheContexts(), array('route'));
}
```

Comment: This answer is 100% incorrect. Do not do this.

Answer (score 1):

By using Service,

```
    use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'UtilitiesDataService' service.
 */
class MyClass {
 

  /**
   * The route match.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface
   */
  protected $routeMatch;

  /**
   * Constructs a new service.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match
   *   The route match.
   */
  public function __construct(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {

    $this->routeMatch = $route_match;
  }

  public function getNodeId(){
    $nid = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('node')->id();
  }
}
```

In services.yml file,

```
services:
   my_module.get_data_service:
    class: Drupal\my_module\MyClass
    arguments: ['@current_route_match']
```

Comment: This is not "by dependency injection" - this is the creation of a new service. You're going to write a new service just to wrap one method of the existing current_route_match service? This is just wrong. Use @Clive's answer, which accesses the current_route_match service directly.

Comment: I think it is correct. A similar example is also in change record link Clive has provided.
The example Sneha has provided is better than a static call others have provided.

Comment: Procedural code would still need to make a static call to `\Drupal`. In this case, using the service defined in this answer or the *current_route_match* service doesn't make any difference, which means the static call isn't removed.

Comment: Agree with @apade. This isn't providing any benefit over making the call to the CurrentRouteMatch class.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are *context aware* and you should be using them. This will allow using the blocks in places where the route itself doesn't have a node but some subsystem provides the context anyways.

Example from core:

```
/**
 * Provides a 'Node Context Test' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "node_block_test_context",
 *   label = @Translation("Node Context Test"),
 *   context_definitions = {
 *     "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", label = @Translation("Node"))
 *   }
 * )
 */
class NodeContextTestBlock extends BlockBase {

  public function build() {
    /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
    $node = $this->getContextValue('node');
```

You can also see how easy it is to get the node. The test this block is used for is instructional: it tests whether the block appears on the preview page. This is not doable with the route match approach as the `/node/preview/{node_preview}/{view_mode_id}` route doesn't contain a node at all.

This will also make the node context required so there's no need to check whether there is a node at all. It's possible to make the node optional, of course:

```
 *     "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", label = @Translation("Node"), required = FALSE)
```

the order of options after the first argument does not matter.