# How to load node object in node preview page?

Tags: 8, nodes

In drupal 8, how do you load the node object in hook_preprocess_page() when on *the node preview page*?

I had a bug come up where [this standard](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/145826/45409) way of loading the current node object was failing on the preview page:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

Answer (score 10):

If you need to use the node object in hook_preprocess_page() on the preview page, you need to use the "node_preview" parameter, instead of the "node" parameter:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

  if ($route_name == 'entity.node.canonical') {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  }
  elseif ($route_name == 'entity.node.preview') {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview');
  }
```

Comment: I was wondering about the preview node for at least a year! Is parameter `node_preview` something new?

Comment: It's loaded from tempStoreFactory, since the node object wouldn't exist in preview.  So it saves it as a separate object with a uuid, that is then retrieved on the preview page.  It's annoying that the variable name is different, but it's a signal that it's not a real node.  So things like $node_preview->url() won't work.  I'm going to have to fix some bugs related to that in my current project.  See nodeForm::preview() for the code that saves the node object and redirects.