# Page Content Type: Displaying error in Preview mode

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

Whenever I am creating or editing a node, in the preview mode I see these errors.

> [image]

This is the code I am using.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function campaigns2019_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node_type']) && $variables['node_type'] === 'landing_page') {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node->field_dark_theme->value) {
      echo("<script>console.log('here');</script>");
      $variables['attributes']['data-theme'] = 'dark';
    }
  }
}
```

The dark theme does not show up in preview mode though. However, if I ignore the errors and create my page, the dark theme works and everything seems to be displayed correctly. When is `template_preprocess_html()` called? Where in Drupal is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is about accessing `field_dark_theme` from an un-existing node instance. The proper way of loading the node during preview [is explained here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246596/how-to-load-node-object-in-node-preview-page).

On the other hand, welcome to the wonderful world of PHP for debugging properly (on Drupal), please check [this post](https://www.webwash.net/drupal-8-debugging-techniques/) and this [documentation entry](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools) check your proper IDE/stack on how to setup debugging tools.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I needed. I'll be looking into it but may have more questions haha really appreciate it though!