# How to add metatags in hook_preproccess_node()?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks, meta-tags

How to add variable meta tags depending on the node that is loaded?

The node has a picture and custom title field and the need to be variable.
What is the best practice to change them in: `hook_preprocess_node()`?

Answer (score 2):

I am aware that this does not directly answer the question, which was about adding in a preprocess function, but I would suggest that you also consider the metatag module, which is pretty full featured.

https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can, place this code in template.php in your subtheme folder

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
        $element = array(
          '#tag' => 'meta', 
          '#attributes' => array(
            'name' => 'robots', 
            'content' => 'index',
          ),
        );
        drupal_add_html_head($element, 'robots');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks allot. However I am working with Drupal 8 (sorry forgot to mention that).  I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905114/what-is-the-drupal-8-equivalent-of-drupal-7s-drupal-add-html-head-within-a-mo but I am not sure if it works in the hook_preproccess_node(). Do you know how it works in 8?

Comment: my code is for D7, not shure if works in D8

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked: 
I managed to load the current node in the hook_preprocess_node().
Based on this answer: [How do I get the current node ID?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145823/how-do-i-get-the-current-node-id)

```
function module_name_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {

            $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
            if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
            // You can get nid and anything else you need from the node object.
            $nid = $node->id();
        }

        $ogImage = array(
            '#tag' => 'meta',
            '#attributes' => array(
                'property' => 'og:image',
                'content' => 'location of the image'.$nid.'.png',
    //my picture has the node id before the file format
            ),
        );

        $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$ogImage, 'ogImage'];
    }
```