# How do I stop the node from caching

Tags: 8, nodes

Sometimes when I run below code in the `hook_preprocess_menu()` of a node, I am getting a previously loaded node instead of my current node.

```
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

What should I do to stop this?

Comment: Have you tried to get the NID and then (re-)load the node? What does that give you? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/206245/15055

Answer (score 1):

If you add node data in a preprocess hook, then you need to add the cache tag of the node:

```
$variables['node_title'] = [
  '#markup' => $node->getTitle(),
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => $node->getCacheTags(),
  ],
];
```

If this node is from a route match, then you need to add a cache context for the route as well:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$variables['node_title'] = [
  '#markup' => $node->getTitle(),
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => $node->getCacheTags(),
    'contexts' => ['route'],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Rather than just getting the cache tags, would it make sense to [add the node as a cacheable dependency](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays#concrete-example) to also get any cache context or max-age settings from it?

Comment: @Andy, you can do this, but you only get a cache tag from the node and you need to add the context for the route yourself. If you write OOP code instead of hooks, then yes, use the methods the objects provide.

Comment: Can you assume you'll _always_ only get a cache tag from the node - for example what if it's a translation, would it then not have a cache context on the language?