# How to acquire (and use) node id in the teaser template of a view?

Tags: views, theming

I tried to find a solution to this problem, but couldn't.  I will describe what I would like to achieve, and hope someone could help.  Sorry if my description is a bit lengthy, I am trying to be detailed in order to help those who could provide advice.

I am building a website for a school.  I have a content type of 'staff'.  I control its appearance by a template file, specifically:

```
/templates/node/node--staff.html.twig
```

In it, I have a

```
{% if teaser == true %}
```

that controls appearance for teaser mode .. Now that works fine, and code for teaser mode gets picked up by views.

The problem is, I use some 'block type' views of staff in 3-4 specific pages, and in there, I would like some custom code each time - according to which page the 'teaser code' is being used by the view.

I tried with `{{ node.id }}` but of course this doesn't work (it gives me the respective node-id of each 'staff'.

So the question is ..  **How can I have the information on which page each block view is currently being used ? To be more precise perhaps, how can I have the information in the 'teaser code' of the content type, so I can customise, according to which view is using the template code?**

I guess I could have different template files for every case, but I would rather avoid it if I can - code will basically be the same, with only a minor string being added each time, so if I can do it with if statements in one file, I 'd rather do that.

My block views are obviously different for each case (to pick up the staff they need) - they 're different block-type views if you understand what I mean.  So if I can somehow put something in the view characteristics that can later help me in the template code, that would be great.

I just don't know how to do it .. **It's the first site I ever build with Drupal, so I might be missing something obvious** ...

I hope I described the problem sufficiently - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if anyone could suggest a better title for this question, please do - this is the best I could come with.

thanks,

thomas

Comment: This question seems to be similar to this question about getting the current node from the route match https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264624/how-do-i-stop-the-node-from-caching/264644, this includes already the next issue you are facing, which is caching.

Comment: thanks. I don't really understand what's going on in there - still haven't used preprocess hooks at all, I guess I need to study them and see how they can help (I guess they can 'pass' information to be used by the template code). I was hoping there could be another way to achieve what I want, because I need it fairly fast .. But if not, I will have to use the long road :)

Comment: Then don't do it, this isn't even good practice, because of caching. I would rather look for a solution in the page template, where {{ node.id }} of the current node is available by default.

Comment: But the {{node.id}} gives me the respective node id of each 'staff' node - i.e., the node-id of each node for which the teaser info is being displayed. So if the block view returns, say, 20 staff members, I get 20 different node IDs. So it cannot be used. I want the page node id within which the block view is being displayed, if you understand what I mean. Sorry for my english, not my native language, I hope it's clear what I mean. That page node id is what I 'm looking for.

Comment: I mean the {{ node.id }} in page.html.twig. This should be the one you are looking for.

Comment: yes, that would be useful .. But I have no idea how to 'pass' that node-id from page.html.twig, to node--staff.html.twig which could then use it to do what I want. If you can help me out, or point to some examples and/or documentation for this, I 'd be grateful ..

Comment: The problem is that node templates are for rendering node data from one node. If you want to inject other data it gets complicated, see the first comment. Another solution as discussed is to render data from the current node in the page template and then use CSS or JS to sort this out client side. Btw. if you are looking for an advanced solution, core would put a placeholder with a lazybuilder in the node.