# Notice: Trying to get property 'nid' of non-object

Tags: 8, uri

In Drupal\rsvplist\Form\RSVPForm->buildForm(), I wrote this to get the current nid:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$nid = $node->nid->value;
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'nid' of non-object in
>   Drupal\rsvplist\Form\RSVPForm->buildForm() (line 30 of
>   modules\custom\rsvplist\src\Form\RSVPForm.php).

I am a new module developer. How to get the current nid in drupal 8?

Comment: What URL are you doing this? Is this form a separate standalone page? The get parameter node will work only on node view pages. Is your form going to be shown in a block under the node? in the node pages?

Comment: Use the `id()` method instead. You also have to check if $node is an instance of NodeInterface because you could be on a route where that won't work (like a user, view, taxonomy, or media route).

Comment: ->getRawParameter() will return just the NID as well

Comment: But that could be any ID, couldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to check if the $node variable is actually an instance of node object.

```
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
  // You can get nid and anything else you need from the node object.
  $nid = $node->id();
}
```

See

[How do I get the current node ID?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145823/how-do-i-get-the-current-node-id)