# Access a page.html.twig template variable in another twig template using a preprocess function

Tags: theming

Drupal core 8.8.3 Version

Using a preprocessor function as below

```
function subtheme_bs_preprocess_book_tree(&$variables) {
  $variables['page_id'] = code here to read the node.nid variable required;
}
```

I can see the node.nid value I need using the kint function on the page.html.twig file, but cannot fathom how to call the variable into my book_tree preprocess function.

I have tried many combinations, and have no idea how to do this.

Image of the 'nid' I would like to access.

For this current page, it's 115.

[image: The node nid - "115" = the current page]

Comment: A book tree is a list of all the book pages, which are nodes. Which node ID are you looking for?

Comment: The nid of the current page

Comment: Short answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/145826/89581

Comment: Thanks @steve for the link.  

`function subtheme_bs_preprocess_book_tree(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $variables['page_id'] = $node->id();
}`  

was the answer to my problem.  

I will definitely add that page to my favorites.