# Add custom access check to user page

Tags: 8, users, routes

I would like to add an additional access condition to viewing user pages like `user/1`.

I looked at the following guidelines, but have not succeeded in coming up with a solution.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

and

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes#access-custom

The module code I have come up with this far - I can restrict all access to user profiles fine.
But I fail at my attempt to get the account id of the page being requested. Once I have the account I can load the field I need to check.

my_module.services.yml

```
services:
  my_module.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

my_module/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 * 
 * We deny access to profiles, if the user has not accepted the terms.
 * 
 * See https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643
 * 
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    $path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    $path_args = explode('/', $path);
    // @todo: the right path does not seem to be accessible here - how do we get the user account id?
    // Always deny access to '/user/{uid}'.
    // Note that the second parameter of setRequirement() is a string.
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.user.canonical')) {

      //$account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account_uid);
      // This effectively denies all access to user profiles
      $route->setRequirement('_access', 'FALSE');
    }
  }

}
```

EDIT:
Based on the comments I tried the following, but I am not being restricted to paths like /user/1, so I guess something is still amiss:

My module structure now looks like this:

```
/my_module
  /src
    /Access
      my_moduleAccessCheck.php
    /Controller
      my_moduleController.php
    my_module.info.yml
    my_module.routing.yml
    my_module.services.yml
```

my_moduleAccessCheck.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\Access\AccessInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

/**
 * Checks access for displaying configuration translation page.
 */
class my_moduleAccessCheck implements AccessInterface {

  /**
   * A custom access check.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for this account.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface
   *   The access result.
   */
  public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
    // Check permissions and combine that with any custom access checking needed. Pass forward
    // parameters from the route and/or request as needed.
    // $account->hasPermission('do example things') && $this->someOtherCustomCondition()
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }

}
```

my_moduleController.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * An example controller.
 */
class my_moduleController extends ControllerBase {

  public function sayHi() {
    dpm('Hi');
  }

}
```

my_module.routing.yml

```
my_module:
  path: '/user/{uid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\my_moduleController::sayHi'
    _title: ''
  requirements:
    _my_module_access_check: 'TRUE'
```

my_module.services.yml

```
services:
  my_module.access_checker:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Access\my_moduleAccessCheck
    arguments: ['@current_user']
    tags:
      - # Required: Mark that this service is for access checks.
        name: access_check, 
        # Optional: Specify which routes this applies to.
        applies_to: _my_module_access_check
```

Comment: So you're viewing */user/1* and you want to get the user object with id=1? I.e. You want to get the user object for the profile being viewed, not the user object of the visitor viewing the page?

Comment: Instead of `_access` you need a dynamic access checking service. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes/advanced-route-access-checking

Comment: @sonfd eventually I will need both the user object for the user profile being viewed and the user role of the currently logged in user.

Comment: See the linked doc: "The access method arguments are resolved similar to normal routing." So you can get both via the method arguments: `access(AccountInterface $account, UserInterface $user)`

Comment: @4k4 I tried to implement the suggested method, but still no success - I added my code in the original question.

Comment: Do you actually need that placeholder/empty/dummy method `sayHi` inside class `my_moduleController` so the Controller isn't empty? Or can you just ignore it and don't pass any controller references, removing line `_controller:` from the routing yml file?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access():

```
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultInterface;
/**
 *
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access().
 */
function my_module_user_access(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {

  // Deny access to user profile for other members if the user hasn't accepted the terms
  if (!$entity->id() === $account->id() 
      || !$entity->hasField('field_profile_visibility')
      || $entity->get('field_profile_visibility')->value === NULL) {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning(t('The profile is not visible because this user has not accepted the terms of this site yet.'));
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *entity.user.canonical* route has one parameter, `$user`. Route parameters can be retrieved from the route object and are upcast to their respective object. So, the user id will be upcast to the user object.

This technique is explained for nodes in the question [How do I get the current node ID](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/145826/48114), but you can do the exact same thing with users.

For example:

```
$profile_user = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('user');
if ($profile_user instanceof \Drupal\user\UserInterface) {
  // $profile_user contains the $user object for the currently viewed profile.
}
```

Comment: The `$profile_user` is `NULL` when I retrieve it from within the `if` clause.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read your question thoroughly enough. I was just answering your question "I fail at my attempt to get the account id of the page being requested. Once I have the account I can load the field I need to check." I didn't realize that the context you were in wouldn't support that idea. I think you should be able to use this snippet in a dynamic access checking service like 4k4 mentioned.

Comment: Thanks I will try that.