# Moving the Answers answer form to a block

Tags: 7

I am using [Answers 7.x-4.0-rc2](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers). Out of the box, the add answer form for a question is at the bottom of the page. I would like to be able to add this form to a block and put it on the left so that in mobile, it will appear at the top and on a regular screen, it will appear at the left.

I am already using [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) in other places on the site so I tried that first. I enabled the add answers node form to become a block and placed it to the left sidebar. This created some sort of infinite loop of page not founds. I tailed watchdog to see [endless reports of the answer node page not being found once it was loaded](https://pastebin.com/x8BJZBD5). Simple solution but didn't work for complex reasons.

The answers form is attached to the question node via the main theme template, `sites/all/modules/contrib/answers/theme/node--answers.tpl.php` for the answers module:

```
<?php if(isset($content['new_answer_form'])): ?>
    <div class="new-answer-form">
      <?php print render($content['new_answer_form']); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif;?>
```

I was able to create a subtheme based on a modification to this theme template in which I moved the add answers form to the top of the page instead of the bottom but am still looking for a way to put it on the left for non-mobile via a block or some other act of Drupal magic. Any feedback is appreciated.

- I am not using [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and do not wish to install it.
- I tried the form block method with and without the form also being attached to the question page via the template

Comment: Probably easier to just create a custom module, implement the proper block hooks to define block, and provide the form to the block via `drupal_get_form`. I have done this many, many times. I don't know all of what Form Block does, but it should be a fairly straightforward thing to do in code and shouldn't result in a redirect loop.

Comment: yeah try, `$form = drupal_get_form('new_answer_form', $nid);
print drupal_render($form);`

Comment: to get the `$nid` see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-nid-of-the-current-node-from-a-module-not-a#238263)